# Java moving an object on a straight line/vector

Tags: java, object, libgdx, line, move

(I am working in libgdx and my arrows are polygons)
I have some programming issue. I'm currently working on a level editor in my game, I've come very far, but now I have a scaling issue. I am working with 8 arrows. Picture below.

[image]

I want to drag the the arrow, or when hovered a huge square in the direction, on a straight line. (Orange line). Every arrow has a direction. The arrows should scale the green square.

[image]

My code, which is shown above, looks like this:

```
public void onDragged(int prevX, int prevY, int cX, int cY) {
    super.onDragged(prevX, prevY, cX, cY);
    int dX = cX - prevX;
    int dY = cY - prevY;
    int pX = x;
    int pY = y;

    Vector2f vector = new Vector2f((float) Math.cos(directionAngle + Math.PI / 2), (float) Math.sin(directionAngle + Math.PI / 2));

    float sum = new Point2f(prevX, prevY).distance(new Point2f(cX, cY));

    x += sum * Integer.signum(dX) * vector.x;
    y -= sum * Integer.signum(dY) * vector.y;
    polygon.setPosition(x, y);
    gui.onArrowDragged(getID(), pX, pY, x, y);
}
```

This solution works very well at the 4 arrows on the squares side, but my problem is, at the other ones, I can still move the arrow in any direction, and not on the vector of the direction.